# Simple Birth Process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, birth-death-process

I am currently studying the **simple birth process** and am stuck in trying to understand the following example.

**EXAMPLE: Setup**

Consider a population in which each individual gives birth after an exponential time of parameter $\lambda$, all independently.

If $i$ individuals are present then the first birth will occur after an exponential time of parameter $i\lambda$.

Then we have $i + 1$ individuals and, by the memoryless property, the process begins afresh.

Hence the population performs a *birth-death-process* with $q_i = i\lambda$.

We denote with $X_t$ the number of individuals at time $t$ and suppose $X_0 = 1$.

Let $T$ be the time of the first birth.

**EXAMPLE: Solution**

We want to calculate $\mathbb{E}(X_t)$,

$$\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}(X_t) & = \mathbb{E}(X_t1_{T \leq t}) + \mathbb{E}(X_t1_{T > t}) \\
 & = \int_0^t \lambda e^{-\lambda s}\mathbb{E}(X_t | T = s)ds + e^{-\lambda t}
\end{align*}$$

Set $\mu(t) = \mathbb{E}(X_t)$, then $\mathbb{E}(X_t | T = s) = 2\mu(t-s)$

Setting $r = t - s$ we get, 
$$\begin{align*}
 e^{\lambda t }\mu(t) = 2\lambda \int_0^t e^{\lambda r} \mu(r) dr
\end{align*}$$

By differentiating we get,

$$\begin{align*}
\mu^{'}(t) = \lambda \mu(t)
\end{align*}$$

and hence we conclude that,

$$\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E} (X_t) = e^{\lambda t}
\end{align*}$$

**QUESTION**

I don't understand the following point in the argument above,

**Why can we immediately conclude that** $\mathbb{E}(X_t | T = s) = 2\mu(t-s)$ **?**

Comment: Because at time $s$, two individuals are born, which each yield in the mean $\mu(t-s)$ descendants $t-s$ units of time after their birth time, that is, at time $t$.

Comment: ok I see. Thank you so much.